# Erlang: include module and call functions

Tags: module, erlang

I am going through Erlang code.

```
tes_lib:check_operational(Config)
```

The above code is present in a module called `Sample.erl`.

I am new to this language. My question is that I cannot see any include statement for the module `tes_lib` in `Sample.erl`. So, how come `Sample.erl` is able to call the function `check_operational` using `tes_lib` module?

I thought that it should be like Java, where we first import the class and then call the function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Erlang, you don't need to "import" modules in order to be able to call them.  A call like `tes_lib:check_operational(Config)` will be resolved at runtime.  If the `tes_lib` module hasn't been loaded yet, the code server will look for it in the load path, and if the module can't be found, the call will fail with an `undef` error.

---

There *is* an `-import` directive in Erlang, but it's usually considered bad style to use it.  You could write:

```
-import(tes_lib, [check_operational/1]).
```

and then call `check_operational` as if it were a local function, without specifying the module name.  Those function calls will be replaced by fully qualified calls at compile time.

From the Erlang [Programming Rules](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#HDR26):

> Don't use `-import`, using it makes the code harder to read since you cannot directly see in what module a function is defined. Use `exref` (Cross Reference Tool) to find module dependencies.