# What's wrong with spawning?

Tags: erlang

I found in documentation of Erlang that the function spawn have a format such `spawn(Module, Name, Args) -> pid()` . I tried that. And it doesn't work. What went wrong?

Code :

```
-module(tut).

-export([main/0]).


main() ->
    spawner(),
    spawner(),
    spawner().

for(Counter) when Counter == 0 ->
    io:fwrite("0");
for(Counter) when Counter > 0 -> 
    io:fwrite("~p\n", [Counter]),
    for(Counter -1).

spawner() ->
    spawn(tut, for, [50]).
```

Console output:

```
68> c(tut).    
tut.erl:12: Warning: function for/1 is unused
{ok,tut}
69> tut:main().
<0.294.0>
=ERROR REPORT==== 6-Sep-2017::15:06:29 ===
Error in process <0.292.0> with exit value:
{undef,[{tut,for,"2",[]}]}
70> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 6-Sep-2017::15:06:29 ===
Error in process <0.293.0> with exit value:
{undef,[{tut,for,"2",[]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 6-Sep-2017::15:06:29 ===
Error in process <0.294.0> with exit value:
{undef,[{tut,for,"2",[]}]}
```

Answer (score 5):

The three-argument version of `spawn` only works when the function you are calling is exported.  To get this to work, you could either export the `for` function in addition to `main`, or use the one-argument version of `spawn`, passing an anonymous function (a 'fun') that makes a local call, thereby bypassing the need to export the function:

```
spawn(fun() -> for(50) end)
```

Comment: Calling the imported function from within `spawn(fun() -> ... end)` should work. The three-argument version wouldn't gain anything from importing functions - you need to specify the original module name. Anyway, importing functions in Erlang is best avoided, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36092365/113848).