# Tangent by scratch

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

I'm completely new to Erlang and i'm using the Ubuntu command line to run the program and gedit to edit/write the code.

I'm trying to code tangent my scratch rather than using the built in math class.

I get the following errors and unsure what needs to be changed.

**ERROR**

```
** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
     in function  math:sqrt/1
        called as math:sqrt(-0.07926409746793839)
        *** argument 1: is outside the domain for this function
     in call from extra:double/1 (extra.erl, line 11)
```

**CODE**

```
-module(extra).

-export([double/1]).

-import(io,[fwrite/1]).

% I am a comment.

double(N) -> 
    Num = math:sin(N),
    Dem = math:sqrt(1 - (Num * 2)),
    Tan = Num / Dem,
    io:fwrite("~w",[Tan]).
```

Comment: `*** argument 1: is outside the domain for this function`... That's coming from `math.sqrt` function application. `sqrt` function requires an argument of `positive` value.

Comment: What was the input you have given which broke this for you?

Comment: I been inputing 0.57 to get this error

Comment: As an aside, you don't actually need the `-import(io, [fwrite/1]).` line in your code. It is usually considered bad style to use `-import` in Erlang - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36092365/113848) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be doing a `Num * Num` instead of `Num * 2` when calculating the `sqrt` for `Dem`.

```
double(N) -> 
    Num = math:sin(N),
    Dem = math:sqrt(1 - (Num * Num)),
    Tan = Num / Dem,
    io:fwrite("~w~n",[Tan]).
```

As the error clearly says...

> *** argument 1: is outside the domain for this function

While doing `math:sqrt(1 - (Num * 2))`, clearly the `Num * 2` is becoming more than `1` causing a negative argument to be fed into `math:sqrt`, and hence the breakage.

***Illustration: `sqrt` with negative argument***

```erlang
> math:sqrt(-1).
math:sqrt(-1).
** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
     in function  math:sqrt/1
        called as math:sqrt(-1)
        *** argument 1: is outside the domain for this function
```

---

---

***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***